# Cache efficient multithreaded merge sort

Tags: c++, multithreading, caching, merge

```
void AFCQueue::ExtractValuesSecComplex(int startIndex, int endIndex,int helperIndex)
{

int size = 0,i,index;
TimeType min_timestamp;
bool is_singleQueue = false;
TimeType* local_queue_time = helper_queue_time[helperIndex];
int* local_queue_value = helper_queue_value[helperIndex];
volatile int& in_local_helper = in_sec[helperIndex];
volatile int& out_local_helper = out_sec[helperIndex];

NodeArrayBlock * heads_local[_MAX_THREADS];
NodeArrayBlock *tails_local[_MAX_THREADS];
int outs_local[_MAX_THREADS];
int ins_local[_MAX_THREADS];
TimeType local_timearray[_MAX_THREADS];
int min_index = 0;

min_timestamp = timestamps_arr[startIndex];
for (i=startIndex,index=startIndex ; i < endIndex; i++){
    heads_local[i] = (NodeArrayBlock *)heads[i];
    outs_local[i]  = outs[i];
    tails_local[i] = (NodeArrayBlock *)tails[i];
    ins_local[i]   = ins[i];
    local_timearray[i] = timestamps_arr[i];

    if (local_timearray[i] < min_timestamp){
        min_timestamp = local_timearray[i];
        index = i;
    }
}

do{
    //if central queue is full 
    while((out_local_helper-1)==in_local_helper || 
        (out_local_helper==0 && in_local_helper == HELPERS_QUEUE_SIZE_1) || _gIsStopThreads){
        if (_gIsStopThreads)
            return;
    }

    local_queue_time[in_local_helper] = heads_local[index]->_timestamp_arr[outs_local[index]];
    local_queue_value[in_local_helper] = heads_local[index]->_values_arr[outs_local[index]++];

    if (in_local_helper < HELPERS_QUEUE_SIZE_1)
        in_local_helper++;
    else
        in_local_helper = 0;    

    if (outs_local[index] == _INIT_SIZE){
        heads_local[index]->_free = true;
        heads_local[index] = heads_local[index]->_next;
        if (heads_local[index]==null)
        {
            tails_local[index] = null;
            ins_local[index]=0;
        }
        outs_local[index] = 0;
    }
    if (ins_local[index] == outs_local[index] &&
        heads_local[index]==tails_local[index])
    {
        //if it was not the last local queue in the array of snapshots
        if (--endIndex != index){
            heads_local[index]                  = heads_local[endIndex];
            tails_local[index]                  = tails_local[endIndex];
            outs_local[index]                   = outs_local[endIndex];
            ins_local[index]                    = ins_local[endIndex];
            local_timearray[index]              = local_timearray[endIndex];
        }
        if ((endIndex-startIndex)==1)
            is_singleQueue = true;
        heads_local[endIndex]                   = null;
    }else{
        local_timearray[index] = heads_local[index]->_timestamp_arr[outs_local[index]];
    }
    //If a single Queue left, no need to check timestamps
    if (is_singleQueue){
        int out = outs_local[startIndex];
        int in  = ins_local[startIndex];
        NodeArrayBlock* he = heads_local[startIndex];
        NodeArrayBlock* ta = tails_local[startIndex];
        int* value_arr = he->_values_arr;
        TimeType* time_arr = he->_timestamp_arr;
        while (true){
            if ((in == out && he==ta))
            {
                //heads[startIndex] = null;
                return;
            }
            if (out == _INIT_SIZE){
                he->_free = true;
                he = he->_next;
                if (he==null)
                {
                    //heads[startIndex]=null;
                    return;
                }
                value_arr = he->_values_arr;
                time_arr = he->_timestamp_arr;
                out = 0;
            }   
            while((out_local_helper-1)==in_local_helper || 
                (out_local_helper==0 && in_local_helper == HELPERS_QUEUE_SIZE_1) || 
                _gIsStopThreads){
                if (_gIsStopThreads)
                    return;
            }

            if (he==ta){
                if (out_local_helper <= in_local_helper){
                    min_index = Math::Min(HELPERS_QUEUE_SIZE-in_local_helper,in-out);
                }else{
                    min_index = Math::Min(out_local_helper-1-in_local_helper,in-out);
                }
            }else{
                if (out_local_helper <= in_local_helper){
                    min_index = Math::Min(HELPERS_QUEUE_SIZE-in_local_helper,_INIT_SIZE-out);
                }else{
                    min_index = Math::Min(out_local_helper-1-in_local_helper,_INIT_SIZE-out);
                }
            }
            memcpy(&local_queue_time[in_local_helper],&time_arr[out],min_index * sizeof(*time_arr));
            memcpy(&local_queue_value[in_local_helper],&value_arr[out],min_index * sizeof(*value_arr));
            in_local_helper+=min_index;
            out+=min_index;
            if (in_local_helper == HELPERS_QUEUE_SIZE)
                in_local_helper = 0;
        }
    }
    if (endIndex==startIndex)
        break;

    min_timestamp = local_timearray[startIndex];
    for(i = startIndex+1,index=startIndex; i < endIndex ;i++){
        if (local_timearray[i] < min_timestamp){
            min_timestamp = local_timearray[i];
            index = i;
        }
    }
}while(true);
}
```

This is a snippet from my algorithm, This function is dedicated for a single thread which iterates over number of queues (there are queues with timestamps and respectively there are queues with values)

each thread that executes this method, iterates over X queues and merge them into single cyclic queue of timestamps and values.

This function suffers from a lot of cache misses,

How could it be improved to reduce cache misses ( multiple threads execute this method simultaneously with different id - helperIndex)

Comment: Retagged as C++ as this is obviously not C code.

Comment: Sounds like homework. If so you must set the homework tag.

Comment: If you are going to post a method, you should post the class as well else the experienced developers in this group will just move on to the next interesting question with code/data that is easy to understand without the mental effort that they are usually paid for.

Comment: This is certainly not a homework , but a part of my research. I prefer not to post any other classes, since this algorithm is still not published, (will be soon). I only need some remarks or comments, where the code is not efficient. Thanks for the comments

Comment: Following on from your comment to my answer, how do you know you're getting cache misses?

Comment: I am using Solaris platform with CC compiler, if i invoke the following commands, which allow the monitoring of different features, i get all the counters i need.  "cputrack -T 9999 -e -f -c (DC_miss / DTLB_miss) ./my_algorithm"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really a code issue, so posting code was not effective.

To limit your cache misses, change the DATA so that each thread only has to work on its own [L1 cache size] chunk at a time.  This is fairly easy with a merge-sort.

A typical, effective merge sort would use a pool of threads and merge-tasks that split up their input partition and spawn child-merges until tasks get a partition that is smaller than [L1 cache size], then use an in-place sort, like quicksort, to finish off the last bits.

The splitting can be done with one extra [data size] buffer that the tasks move data between as they do their insertion-sort afer the quicksorts have been done.  there should be no need for any memcopying.

Just taking single-threaded in-line code and tring to get it to work on multiple threads, without consideration of the data, is just not effective.

Comment: Thanks for the observation, my main problem on working with local queues, is that a main merge thread that will merge the local queues of the helper threads need to know about the local queues, and need to take them into account (it runs simultaneously and tries to merge it in central array), I tried copying the part of global queues that is relevant to the helper to local variables, although it didn't helped me so much.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you have a lot of cache misses. What you have to remember is that there is only one bus between the CPU and L3 cache and RAM. So if thread one is busy reading memory and then gets suspended to allow another thread to do the same thing but using different memory, the cache will need to be reloaded. This also happens when the process gets suspended - when the process resumes execution, the cache needs reloading.

To limit your cache misses, limit the number of threads to the number of physical cores (ignore hyper threaded cores). If you have more threads than cores, then the cache will need updating every time there's a thread switch. If you have the same number of threads and cores, you reduce the chance of losing your cache to another thread / process. You want to try num_cores - 1 threads and see if that helps.

Also, your code is quite large and uncommented. Hard to see what, exactly, you're doing.

Comment: The code has no data.  I looked briefly at it and gave up.  The OP probably needs to reorganize the data to get a good benefit from multiple threads, (though since there's no data, it's difficult to be sure:).

Comment: @MartinJames: Yeah, the OP would benefit from analysing the data more. Limiting the number of threads would also help, possibly more so if each thread's affinity is set to a single CPU.

Comment: Sorry about the large uncommented code, i will try to reload more understandable code, regarding the number of cores, i have 64 cores and 128 GB ram, i am running only 8 helper threads.